# How to limit disk performance?

Tags: performance, hard-drive, load-testing

I am load-testing a web application and studying the impact of some config tweaks (related to disk i/o) on the overall app performance, i.e. the amount of users that can be handled simultaneously.

But the problem is that I hit 100% CPU before I can see any effect of the disk-related config settings. I am therefore wondering if there is a way I could deliberately limit the disk performance so that it becomes the bottleneck and the tweaks I am trying to play with actually start impacting performance. Should I just make the hard disk busy with something else? What would serve the best for this purpose?

More details (probably irrelevant, but anyway): PHP/Magento/Apache, studying the impact of `apc.stat`. Setting it to `0` makes APC not checking PHP scripts for modification which should increase performance where disk is the bottleneck. Using JMeter for benchmarking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtualization. I don't know about VMWare, but Hyper-V now - 2012 R2 - allows one to set IOPS Limits for a virtual machine. Handy to put in some really low number.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [ionice](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/ionice.htm) -c3 **yourjob** .

This will limit the io to when the system is idle.

See also [AskUbuntu link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173998/how-do-i-run-an-i-o-intensive-application-only-when-the-computer-is-idle).